# How to inspect/read a Java file inside a Gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, gradle-plugin

I am writing a Gradle plugin that needs to scan Kotlin files and find if there is a certain interface included in the class. For example, with this snippet of code:

```
class MyClass {
    interface MyInterface {
        fun doSomething()
    }
}
```

my plugin would print on the console that the interface *MyInterface* was found, and for this snippet:

```
class MySecondClass {}
```

would not print anything.

I have successfully created the plugin structure and a *DefaultTask* like this, where I get the file that needs to be inspected from the user input (written in Kotlin):

```
open class MyGradleTas : DefaultTask() {

    @InputFile lateinit var inputFile: File
    @OutputDirectory lateinit var outputDirectory: File

    @TaskAction
    fun run() {
        // How can I inspect the Java/Kotlin code inside the inputFile object
    }
}
```

How can I inspect the inputFile *File* object? Is there a way to transform it to UAST or PSI? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

So I found this project: http://javaparser.org/ that I believe it will put me in the right direction, but any suggestions are welcome, since I do not know if this is the preferred/right approach

Comment: I would say that using a parser is definitely the safest and cleanest approach, since you won't have to worry about parsing text yourself and tracking the code structure.  (If you were looking for `interface` by simply scanning the text, you'd have to make sure it wasn't commented out code, for example.)  JavaParser looks like it's suitable for the job, which is all that really matters.

Comment: I believe the JavaParser does not work with Kotlin files. I posted a message on the  Github page here: https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/issues/1640

Comment: Ah, my apologies.  I just checked the suitability of the API; I assumed because you suggested it that it handled Kotlin.  My bad.  It looks like there might be a couple of leads linked from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45956449/how-to-parse-kotlin-code)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your thought that using a parser is the correct way to approach this.  I found [a discussion of parsing Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45956449/how-to-parse-kotlin-code) that has pointers to 2 projects on GitHub that use [antlr4 grammars to parse Kotlin](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/kotlin).  [The second project](https://github.com/sarahBuisson/kotlin-parser) appears to be basically a copy of the first, but provides slightly more useful examples of how to use it.

Comment: Based on those READMEs, I have no idea how to use those tools, but seems to point in the right direction...

Comment: This should help to understand those tools: https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial/